# How to turn a MERN app into a desktop app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, mern

I am very new in front-end application development. I made a MERN application in react, divided into two parts, a frontend and a backend. Now they all work fine, but I want to turn them into a desktop application that can be executed by itself, so that I don't have to enter commands like npm start or npx nodemon in VScode. I successfully packaged the front-end with electron, but I don't know how to handle the part of connecting to the server in the backend and how to pack it with frontend together.

Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running it in your local environment using the commands you want to access it directly right?

So, you have to deploy your application on any server, your application will be built on the server and you can access your application using the link.

For that, you can use Netlify for deploying your frontend code and OnRender for deploying your backend code which are free to use.

First, try to deploy your backend after that make the changes with the new link and endpoints with the frontend and deploy your frontend code.

Now you can directly access your application from any device.

Hope this helps your question